# combinations from different amounts of subjects of which some are different and some the same

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have three actor roles that need to be filled, Batman, Robin, Joker.
There are different amounts of actors auditioning for each part and some are auditioning for more than one part.  An actor cannot perform more than one part.  He can only win one role.

How many combinations are there of the actors and roles?   What is the formula to figure that out?

Seems like standard uses of combinations are permutations are not applicable here. The number of possible actors differs for each role.  Some roles have the same people and some do not.

Example using letters for actors

Batman
A
B
C
D

Robin
A
B
C

Joker
A
I

Handwritten out with say a tree, gives 13 possible combinations.  Not sure of the math behind that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the number of *systems of distinct representatives* (SDRs) of the sets of possible actors for each role. As you have noted, you can work out the number using a tree. However, it is very unlikely that there is a formula for the answer in general. Counting SDRs is equivalent to computing the permanent of a $(0,1)$-matrix, which is [#P-complete by a remarkable theorem of Valiant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-completeness_of_01-permanent).

Comment: Fascinating. Validating that I couldn't figure out such a formula to get a count. Fascinating nevertheless.